# event tracking with google analytics.js when a div is removed its display property to none

Tags: jquery, events, google-analytics, tracking

I have some elements that I want to track with google analytics (ga, analytics.js) for some event.

The first thing, I want to track is when display property of an element is removed from none to when an element is being displayed.

The html:

```
<div class="boxzilla-container boxzilla-bottom-right-container">
<div class="boxzilla boxzilla-386 boxzilla-bottom-right" style="display: none; overflow-y: auto; max-height: none;">
    <div class="boxzilla-content">
        <div id="gray-strip" class="gf-footer">
            <h2 class="gf-head">CLICK HERE TO CLAIM YOUR<span class="gf-head-read"> FREE TRIAL</span></h2>
        </div>
    </div><span class="boxzilla-close-icon">×</span></div> </div>
```

### URl: http://www.tribemainline.com/home-test/

I want to track when '.boxzilla-386' has removed its property from display: none to no property.

The other thing, I want to track when '.boxzilla-386 .boxzilla-close-icon' has been clicked.

This is little bit a mix of tracking and jQuery: 
When, somebody clicks on the '.boxzilla-386', it should be hidden with slide-in effect and bring the opt-in box. Currently, when '.boxzilla-386' is clicked, the opt-in pop-up shows up, but '.boxzilla-386' does not go away. When it does, I want to track this events too.

Comment: URL: http://www.tribemainline.com/home-test/

Answer (score 0):

Boxzilla actually has built-in events that it fires whenever the close icon is clicked or when a box is just showing up, so it would be best & easiest to just use those.

```
Boxzilla.on('box.show', function(box) {
    console.log("Showing box " + box.id);
});

Boxzilla.on('box.dismiss', function(box) {
    console.log("Dismissing box " + box.id);
});
```

For some more information about the available events, the README on GitHub has some more examples: [ibericode/boxzilla.js](https://github.com/ibericode/boxzilla.js)

Inside the function callback, you can trigger your Google Analytics logic. Please note that if you're using the WordPress plugin, there's a dedicated add-on plugin which does this for you: [Boxzilla - Google Analytics](https://boxzillaplugin.com/add-ons/google-analytics/).

Hope that helps. Good luck!